# Is there a way to remove trailing spaces and convert tabs to spaces in a lot of files at once using command-line?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using cygwin and have a lot of files in which I want to convert tabs to spaces (four spaces per tab) and remove all space characters that exist at end of line. Is there a utility for this in Linux?

Comment: You are searching for `sed`

Answer (score 2):

**[sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)** is your friend for that. Comes for free with all Linux distros, as far as I know. It's the "Stream EDitor", and works with [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). To apply it to your example:

```
sed -E 's/\t/    /g;s/\s*($)/\1/g' infile outfile
```

Each tab (`\t`) is replaced by 4 spaces, and trailing spaces (actually, all whitespace characters up to the end of the line (`$`) are removed. If you don't want the result in a new file, you can tell `sed` to do the replacements inline (`-i`):

```
sed -i -E 's/\t/    /g;s/\s*($)/\1/g' file
```

In a lot of files? No prob:

```
sed -i -E 's/\t/    /g;s/\s*($)/\1/g' *
```

(just pass a "mask", like `*.txt` or whatever files should be matched).

You can get `sed` from your distro's package management, e.g. `apt install sed`.

Comment: What language is 's/\t/    /g;s/\s*($)/\1/g'? Is that a regular expression? I don't see the digit 4 anywhere in the regular expression. What is going on here?

Comment: Yes, it's regular expression. And no, the question wasn't asking for digits – but the replacement part has 4 spaces as requested. Just try it out with some sample files (I did, and it does what you asked for). The trailing `/g` makes sure it's applied Globally, so all tabs are replaced by 4 spaces each.

Comment: I am just curious to know, how did you specify the "4 spaces" part?

Comment: By using 4 spaces? The big gap following the `\t/` are 4 spaces. `sed` syntax is `s/<RegExToMatch>/<replacement>/<op>`, basically meaning `s`earch for this `<RegEx>` and replace it according to `<replacement>` applying `<op>`. You can concatenate multiple operations using a `;`. So taking the first part, it means `s`earch for a `\t`ab, replace it by 4 spaces, `g`lobally. The second part is `s`earch for white-`\s`paces up to the EOL (`$`) and replace that with the EOL (back reference: `\1`  is the first `(match)`).